# Pass BehaviorSubject value as parameter

Tags: angular, rxjs6, behaviorsubject

I have an Angular component with a BehaviourSubject initialized to the current month:

```
textLabel: string;

private monthIndex$: BehaviorSubject<number>;

private MONTHS = [
"Gennaio",
"Febbraio",
"Marzo",
"Aprile",
"Maggio",
"Giugno",
"Luglio",
"Agosto",
"Settembre",
"Ottobre",
"Novembre",
"Dicembre"
];

constructor(private listService: ShoppingListService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.monthIndex$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(new Date().getMonth());

  // Like this it does not display the label
  this.setMonthLabel(this.monthIndex$.value); 

  this.model$ = this.monthIndex$.pipe(
    switchMap((monthValue: number) => {
      //    this.setMonthLabel(monthValue);  // This way it works!
      return this.listService.getHistoryChartModel(monthValue);
    }),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  );
}

private setMonthLabel(monthIndex: number) {
  this.textLabel = this.MONTHS[monthIndex];
}

setMonth(direction: number) {
  let monthIndex = this.monthIndex$.getValue();
  monthIndex += direction;
  monthIndex =
  monthIndex < 0 ? 0 : monthIndex > 11 ? 11 : monthIndex;

  this.monthIndex$.next(monthIndex);
  this.setMonthLabel(monthIndex);
}
```

And the template:

```
<div class="view-sel-container">
  <button
   color="primary" mat-icon-button
   (click)="setMonth(-1)"
   [disabled]="monthIndex === 0">
  <i class="material-icons">
    keyboard_arrow_left
  </i>
 </button>

 <span class="label-text" *ngIf="textLabel">{{ textLabel }}</span>

 <button
  color="primary" mat-icon-button
  (click)="setMonth(1)"
  [disabled]="monthIndex === 11">
  <i class="material-icons">
    keyboard_arrow_right
  </i>
 </button>
```

Is it a timing reason why by passing the BehavourSubject value to the method `this.setMonthLabel(this.monthIndex$.value)`, the label is not displayed in the template?

**UPDATE**

The solution provided by Deborah Kurata using get/set instead of BehaviourSubject is the best way to go. I leave the original question/code open as I still do not get why the code does now work by passing the behaviourSubject value as parameter.

Comment: now that I look at you code deaper, instead of switchMap, you should use tap

Comment: Seems that this code could easily be accomplished with simple properties and no `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`. IMHO, `Subject/BehaviorSubject` are used *much* too often when simple properties would suffice ... making the code much more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @Sandra: the monthIndex$ is changed via the template (as it shows months views), therefore the user might quickly click on "next month" multiple times, therefore I want to satisfy only the latest request. I updated the question with the method changing the monthIndex$.

Comment: Here is a simple example without the Subject/BehaviorSubject: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpusk2

Comment: Thanks Deborah for the example, I already changed the textLabel to be simply a string. However as the "monthIndex$" value can change via template interaction (the user can select the next or previous month), I thought I need a BehaviourSubject in order to request new data from the service according to the actual monthIndex$ value.

Comment: I just updated the stackblitz to include that additional feature of a user-defined month index. You can use a getter/setter as a much easier way to handle changes than a `BehaviorSubject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider going with something like this that does not require a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`:

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './history-chart.component.html'
})
export class HistorChartComponent {
  textLabel: string;
  model$: Observable<any>;

  private _monthIndex: number;
  get monthIndex(): number {
    return this._monthIndex;
  }
  set monthIndex(value: number) {
    console.log("setter called with: " + value);
    // Set the label
    this.setMonthLabel(value);
    // Get the data
    this.getMonthData(value);
    this._monthIndex = value;
  }

  private MONTHS = [
    "Gennaio",
    "Febbraio",
    "Marzo"
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // This calls the setter
    this.monthIndex = new Date().getMonth();
  }

  // Increment or decrement the month index
  // This calls the setter
  setMonth(value: number) {
    this.monthIndex += value;
  }

  private setMonthLabel(monthIndex: number) {
    this.textLabel = this.MONTHS[monthIndex];
  }

  private getMonthData(monthIndex: number): void {
    // Commented out because I don't have the service code
    //this.model$ = this.listService.getHistoryChartModel(monthIndex);

    // Faking out the call to the service
    this.model$ = of(
      { id: 1, value: "some data for month : " +  this.MONTHS[monthIndex] },
    );
  }
}
```

The setter is automatically called each time the user changes the value OR when the value is changed in code. So the setter is a good place to execute any code that needs to respond to the change.

With the code above, the data for the month is retrieved on ngOnInt AND every time the user clicks either of the buttons. If you are not seeing this behavior with the provided stackblitz, please let me know.

**Template**

```
<div class="view-sel-container">
    <button
   color="primary" mat-icon-button
   (click)="setMonth(-1)"
   [disabled]="monthIndex === 0">
  <i class="material-icons">
    keyboard_arrow_left
  </i>
 </button>

 <span class="label-text" *ngIf="textLabel">{{ textLabel }}</span>

 <button
  color="primary" mat-icon-button
  (click)="setMonth(1)"
  [disabled]="monthIndex === 11">
  <i class="material-icons">
    keyboard_arrow_right
  </i>
 </button>

<div>
<span class="label-text" *ngIf="textLabel">
 {{textLabel}}
</span>
</div>
<div *ngIf="(model$ | async) as model">
  <div>
  {{ model.value }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the associated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpusk2

Comment: I updated my question adding the call from the template to set the new month. If I use set/get for the monthIndex and I call the method `this.listService.getHistoryChartModel` with it (I need it on  Init and not in the SetLabel Method), it does not trigger a new request. Therefore I originally used a BehaviourSubject. Am I still missing something?

Comment: I use this approach in my courses *and* have clients that have used the getter/setter approach in their line of business applications. If it is not working for you, please fork and update my stackblitz to show where it is not working.

Comment: Thanks again, I will check it. As a sake of interest, do you know why by passing the BehavourSubject value to the setMonthLabel did not work, while it did inside the switchMap? This was my orignal question (even if you are totally right in trying to avoid BehaviourSubject if not needed)

Comment: It works great. It is very interesting to see it (now) under a different perspective and how simple can the code be kept!

Comment: Great to hear! I'm relooking at your original code trying to answer your original question ... but I can't get this code to work: `const monthIndex += direction;` If the code is declaring this value here and then either adding or subtracing one, won't this *always* be 1 or -1? Not the correct `monthIndex`?

Comment: One line was missing (just updated). I initialize monthIndex (as BehaviorSubject value) to the current month and then add or subtract 1 from the Template to switch to the next/previous month respectively.

Comment: BTW, the `switchMap` code seems to work if you remove the `takeUntil`. You can find a discussion of why `switchMap` and `takeUntil` behave as they do here: https://blog.strongbrew.io/building-a-safe-autocomplete-operator-with-rxjs/: `Because the term$ observable is keeping track of the last value, the takeUntil operator will always have a value, resulting in the fact that every XHR call gets aborted immediately.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188686/discussion-between-francesco-and-deborahk).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.monthIndex$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(new Date().getMonth());

  // Like this it does not display the label
  this.setMonthLabel(this.monthIndex$.value); 

  this.model$ = this.monthIndex$.pipe(
    tap(monthValue => {
      this.setMonthLabel(monthValue);
      return this.listService.getHistoryChartModel(monthValue);
    }),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  );
```

1. You should use tap for anything that is a side-effect.
2. I dont know why you would need to use `this.setMonthLabel(this.monthIndex$.value)` when you have the value already in your pipe?
3. What does `this.setMonthLabel` do?